# Roguelike Tabletop

Tags: game-recommendation, fantasy

I am looking for a Roguelike tabletop RPG to play with some friends. We really love RPG's we love the Concept of D&D (talk-gaming) but we just dwell into a lot of silliness due to not having a good DM (you know Dwarfs getting drunk, Elves stealing flowers from gardens those kinds of things).

What we do are love Action RPGs on the PC (Diablo (not 3), Baldur's Gate, Titan Quest). Also we've played quite a lot of Magic: The Gathering due to the battle (solid rules component). Recently we have started with Dungeons & Dragons Miniatures. And it's fun, but "just a battle".

What we are looking for is a Tabletop RPG that combines these things, A set of rules, a Dungeon, action, miniatures and roguelike-ish elements (Unidentified items, leveling, perma-death, random dungeons/encounters etc)

Also we've bought Legend of Drizt and Dungeonquest. And I myself like aspects of those games, but not the games themselves much. Drizt is missing competition, playing against a 'board' *feels* pointless. It's not much different than playing against a computer. But nevertheless it feels weird. And Dungeonquest is missing the aspect of playing against each other. In both games I love the dungeon generating.

Anyway, give me a hoot were I can find a game within my genre? (tabletop nethack would just rule)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. You seem to be focusing on D&D; there are *thousands* of other RPG systems available, but if your group is particularly interested in staying within the D&D franchise, that's fine--we just need to know for sure so we can answer accordingly. And since you have 20+ rep on another site, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking for a [board game](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/)? There are many that would suit what you are looking for.

Comment: Well boardgames are often not 'deep'. You play a campaign and it's done. That is all. I want to evolve my characters, (if they survive)

Comment: @Stolas Character development and campaigns can occur in, say, Warhammer 40k and its cousins (though I would not recommend any of them unless there's ones that don't cost crazy amounts).

Comment: What would you say is missing or extraneous to you in D&D? The need for a "competent" GM? Random generation of dungeons/adventures? Because everything else you say seems to fit. Intra-group competition is not always a good thing when trying to accomplish something, but if that's what you're looking for, just fight or compete amongst yourselves as you will :). Also, are you looking for an open-ended ruleset or do you want *everything* you are allowed to do in-game to be codified in a way more similar to Magic The Gathering (or a boardgame)?

Comment: thomax, well I've always bought of Board Games being accessible RPGs, just like Legend of Drizt but I feel most of you don't agree on this. I'll read some reviews on Drakon, thanks for the advice.
leokhorn, You say D&D seems to fit, this is why I've been looking within the D&D universe. I like what drizt has done to make a "competent" GM. Or what the RPG-'books' do (like gamebook adventures). I really like to have some things open, but not confusing. To elaborate, D&D Mini attacks, TONS of rulebooks attract. But rules like: "the GM acts as god and changes the rules as he seems fit" does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend the 4e "mod" of [Fourthcore](http://svdpress.com/fourthcore/). The tone is very reminiscent of the absolute brutality of nethack, and my preferred means of play is to set a timer for the *players* and allow a dungeon reset when the inevitable TPK happens. This creates an *amazingly* roguelike feel as the players use iterative deaths to "solve" the dungeon against a challenging deadline. (Especially, remember that encounters reset, so this encourages alternate-path thinking that is so very critical to ascending with the amulet.)

Hacking on potion mixing would be trivial. Simply start with a list of colours and a spreadsheet with a random function and vlookup mapped to the potions found (and you can certainly include more in dungeons without any trouble.) At the start of a run, you hit refresh, and all the colours are mixed up.